# Why does my use of System.Threading.Timer not work?

Tags: c#, timer

I'm trying to execute a function periodically, using a `System.Threading.Timer`. It calls the function, but it doesn't work, and doesn't report an error. Why?

```
 public class Timerr
 {
    ArrayList listurl;
    ArrayList listcategory;
    protected Collection<Rss.Items> list = new Collection<Rss.Items>();
    RssManager reader = new RssManager();
    System.Threading.Timer Timer;
    System.DateTime StopTime;
    public void Run()
    {
        StopTime = System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
        Timer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0,1000);
    }

    private void TimerCallback(object state)
    {
        if (System.DateTime.Now >= StopTime)
        {
            Timer.Dispose();
            return;
        }
        callrss();
    }
}
```

Comment: @mellamokb: There is no such method on the `System.Threading.Timer` class. Constructing a `System.Threading.Timer` is sufficient to start it. Don't be so hasty. Every single person that upvoted your comment should have 100 reputation points docked.

Comment: the code as is should work - have you tried setting a break point in your callback?

Comment: @Jason: Good call! :P  Comment duly removed.

Comment: "It calls the function" - how have you determined this, when you have no other information than "it doesn't work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in LINQPad:

```
void Main()
{
    var t = new Timerr();
    t.Run();

    Thread.Sleep(60000);
}

public class Timerr
 {
    System.Threading.Timer Timer;
    System.DateTime StopTime;
    public void Run()
    {
        StopTime = System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
        Timer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0,1000);
    }

    private void TimerCallback(object state)
    {
        if (System.DateTime.Now >= StopTime)
        {
            Timer.Dispose();
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
```

I recommend you install the free [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) with which you can check such things very quickly, without the need to run your entire application

Comment: All you're doing is dumping code on him that is the natural outgrowth of the questions I asked in my answer. It doesn't teach him anything.

Comment: @Jason - No, all I'm doing is giving him the tools to solve problems on his own. I'm also showing him how to separate the wheat from the chaff in order to isolate his problems. You, however, are confusing him with abstract concepts about which he probably knows very little, providing zero code to go along with them.

Comment: @leventkalay92 I added the `Thread.Sleep` call just so the process remains alive long enough for some callbacks to be invoked (so you'll see some "Hello" printouts)

Comment: @ohadsc: Clearly the "copying and pasting" code from the Internet is what got him in this position in the first place.

Comment: Well. This certainly wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Did you construct an instance of `Timerr`? Did you call `Run` on that instance? Did you keep that instance around so that the timer isn't GCed (`System.Threading.Timer`s aren't automatically rooted, like `System.Timers.Timer`s are)? Do you have some busy loop or some other way of keeping your process alive long enough to allow the timer callback to be invoked?

Comment: @leventkalay92, Jason is implying that you need to do all of these things to make your code work.

Comment: Well, that's the problem. You need to do the things I suggested: in your `Main` loop you need to instantiate a `Timerr`, you need to invoke `Run` on that `Timerr`, you need to make sure that the instance isn't GCed prematurely, and you need to keep your process alive so that the callback has a chance to be fired by the timer. I suspect that you're a nascent C# developer. You'll learn a lot if you figure out for yourself what these things mean and how to do these things on your own, rather than us just dumping code on you.